# TypeError: _reactDom.default.createElement is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router, react-router-dom

I'm a beginner in React and stuck with some problem.I'm using server rendering and uses express as server and Getting an error message - TypeError: _reactDom.default.createElement is not a function. I have checked for solutions from various sites couldn't find any solution.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Route from 'react-router-dom';
import {StaticRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.hydrate(
 <Router><App /></Router> ,
  document.getElementById('mountNode'),
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Route,Switch,browserHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';


import HomePage from './HomePage';
import About from './About';
export default function App()
{

const history = createMemoryHistory();
return (
<Router history={browserHistory}> 
     <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>  
    </Switch>
</Router>
);
}
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: _reactDom.default.createElement is not a function
at HomePage (C:\LMS-APP\src\components\/HomePage.js:10:17)
at processChild (C:\LMS-APP\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3043:14)
at resolve (C:\LMS-APP\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2960:5)
at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (C:\LMS-APP\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3435:22)
at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (C:\LMS-APP\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3373:29)
at Object.renderToString (C:\LMS-APP\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3988:27)
at C:\LMS-APP\src\server\/server.js:10:40
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\LMS-APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\LMS-APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\LMS-APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "LMS-APP",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server/server.js --ignore dist/",
    "dev-bundle": "webpack -w -d"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

**HomePage.js**

```
import React from 'react-dom';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function HomePage()
{
    return(
         <div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/about">About</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
         </div> 
    );
}
```

**server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import App from '../components/App';

const server = express();
server.use(express.static('dist'));

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const initialMarkup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);

  res.send(`
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mountNode">${initialMarkup}</div>
    <script src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
  `)
});

server.listen(4242, () => console.log('Server is running...'));
```

Answer (score 5):

In your HomePage.js , you have imported

```
import React from "react-dom";
```

which should clearly be imported from "react".[The React Documentation should help](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html).
So the fix is :

```
import React from "react";
```

Answer (score 0):

From `react-router-dom`, the [documentation on ssr](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering)  suggests that `StaticRouter` is used on the server while `BrowserRouter` is used in the client.

In your example the file `index.js` is ran in the client, so my suggestion is to remove the Router tag from this file.

Comment: I have removed the router tag and also tried by adding BrowserRouter as stated above but for both case still getting the same error.

Comment: Please make sure you have only one Router tag in your client.

Comment: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<StaticRouter><App /></<StaticRouter>)

Comment: And remove the <StaticRouter> from the client

Comment: Getting this Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object - after removing StaticRouter from the client and Add this - <StaticRouter><App /></<StaticRouter> in server. Please find the detailed error below.

Comment: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214553/discussion-between-abhijeet-and-carlosbf).